# Rest api design issue - nested url params or url with query elements

Tags: rest, express

I am using express as router with mysql.

Blogs and Comments are two entities in database (MySql) and are related by foreign key.

Traditional REST api design will be like below:

```
blog/:blogId
blog/:blogId/comments/:commentId
```

I was thinking of an equivalent like below because I do not want a nested route - instead
all additional things will be in request query. This kind of makes code modular and not interlinked in backend.

```
blog/:blogId
comments/:commentId?blog=blogId
```

I know it kind of goes against grain of rest api.

What would be the pitfalls if I proceed with apis I am thinking ? Can anybody point to an example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, passing data as query param is not desirable. Usually in norms query param data are those data which are not mandatory, in other sense even if you don't pass query param the API should not fail, in your case if blogId is not passed what comments it will return? I think blogId is a mandatory field

But you can use something like

```
    blog/:blogId
    comments/:commentId/blog/:blogId
```

But I understand your apprehension of the relationship as blog is not child of comment as one would see from API signature, but then can we achieve the exact relationship in API signature?

Comment: For your question on what would api : comments/:commentId return - Error: blogId missing. I am ok with bending of rules / norms here - but technically will there any be short comings.

Comment: I honestly don't see any issue with having your choice of the API name technically, REST is pretty flexible.

Comment: After a minute - I feel right error to your original question of missing blogId - error should have been : Error invalid URL - this is when we compare to 'right-rest' implementation. 
The point Im thinking over and over is - I want to avoid having routes for comments module in blog module. So if I goto conventional way of defining routes blogs/:blogId in blog module and blogs/:blogid/comments/:commentId in comments module - need to check if this is ok with express.

Comment: I kind of got your problem, well even if the comment is inside blog you can map your /blog/:blogId/comments/:commentId URL to comment module, there is no point writing your comments code inside blog module.